# Gendern in Adjektiven: benutzerfreundlich?

Tags: adjective, gender, gender-neutrality

Wie gendert man hier richtig?

- *Benutzer*innenfreundlich*?

(can't find that in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/benutzerfreundlich))

Comment: "Richtig gendern" ist eine contradictio in adjecto; die Quadratur des Kreises. Gendern beruht auf falschen Prämissen und verletzt vorsätzlich die richtige Sprache. Du kannst allenfalls pol. korrekt gendern.

Comment: So ist es. Vergiss den Quatsch. Schreib einfach "benutzerfreundlich".

Comment: Es ist in Ordnung, wenn man Gendering ablehnt. Aber wieso muss man Fragen zu dem Thema abwerten? Ich denke, auch den Gegnern der Praxis sollte klar sein, dass sich in diesem Bereich (verschiedene, umstrittene) Normen herausgebildet haben, zu denen man Fragen stellen und gute Antworten im Sinne der Seite schreiben kann.

Comment: @DavidVogt Welch ein Glück, daß den Freunden des Genderns jeder Gedanke an ein moralisches Framing ihrer Sache fremd ist. Die kämen niemals auf die Idee, hier mit Begriffen wie "gerecht" und "ungerecht" zu hantieren und die Meinung der anderen abzuwerten.

Comment: *Lest bitte [unsere Regeln für Fragen über gendergerechte Sprache u. Ä.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1340), bevor ihr Kommentare schreibt.*

Comment: @userunknown Auch mir gefällt das Gendern (meistens) nicht, aber eine "richtige Sprache" gibt es auch nicht. Ich akzeptiere die Realität.

Comment: @KritikerderElche: Es gibt falsche Sprache, so wie "Mir schmerzt die Fuß" oder "... das Nase"  oder "... der Gehirn". Das ist einfach alles falsch. Oder "Peter ist ein Person des öffentlichen Lebens" ist auch falsch. Die Regeln sind Deduktionen aus natürlichem Sprachgebrauch und das feministische Neusprech ist eine bewusste Verletzung der Regeln zur Überwindung eines vorgestellten Patriarchats. Es gibt eine richtige Sprache, aber für viele verbietet sich diese aufgrund ihres Opportunismus. Und dann stellt man Fragen wie "Wie schieße ich mir richtig ins Knie?" oder "Wie schlage ich mein Kind?".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it violates logic, and from contradictory premises, you may follow everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Duden empfiehlt, in solchen Fällen mit Ersatzkonstruktionen kreativ zu werden, die den direkten Personenbezug vermeiden, zum Beispiel:

> benutzungsfreundlich

Quelle ist dieser Artikel der Duden-Sprachberatung; das Wort *benutzerfreundlich* ist hier auch als Beispiel aufgeführt: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/gendern-komposita-personenbezeichnungen

Wer sich berufen fühlt, kann natürlich auch *benutzer*innenfreundlich* schreiben, Regeln in diesem Bereich haben sich noch nicht voll ausgebildet.  Je nach Kontext und Umfeld wird der Genderstern allerdings als aktivistisch wahrgenommen, er ist nicht Teil der Standardsprache und kann als persönliches Statement verstanden werden oder auf Ablehnung stoßen, was gewünscht sein kann oder auch nicht. Ersatzkonstruktionen sind in dieser Hinsicht neutraler.

Comment: Ersatzkonstruktionen mögen grammatikalisch zulässig sein, das allein macht sie nicht idiomatisch. Solange sie nicht idiomatisch sind, werden sie als nicht-standardsprachlich wahrgenommen. Man spürt die Absicht und ist verstimmt.

Comment: ich gebe mich mit "benutzungsfreundlich" zufrieden :-)

Comment: @Uwe: das Perfide an der Polarisierung ist halt, dass immer irgendjemand "verstimmt" ist, egal wie man es macht. Das gilt offenbar auch für Fragen und Antworten zu diesem Thema,